# Vue how to assign prop data to arraylist

Tags: javascript, vue.js

In my `vue`-application I want to assign prop data to an arraylist.

```
<MyComponent :mydata="someArrayData" />
```

In "MyComponent" I want to do this:

```
props: {
   mydata: {
      type: Array,
      default: []
   }
}
data(){
   arrayList: []
}
created(){
   this.arrayList = this.$props.mydata;
}
```

but then "this.arrayList" is empty - when I do `console.log(this.$props.mydata)` it returns the data.

what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Isn't there an error in the console telling you "data functions should return an object"?  Your data function doesn't return anything

Answer (score 1):

I actually managed to solve it by simply adding:

```
<div v-if="someArrayData.length">
   <MyComponent :mydata="someArrayData" />
</div>
```

now it works for me!

Thanks for the help anyway!

Answer (score 0):

you do not need 'this' in the data properties:

```
props: {
   mydata: {
      type: Array,
      default: []
   }
}
data(){
   arrayList: []
}
created(){
   this.arrayList = this.$props.mydata;
}
```

Comment: ah sorry, my bad - I actually didnt have "this" in the data properties - updated my question.